# Button to new sale order from own module in odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

How can i create a link to a new sales order from a own made module (with odoo studio) where the customer data is already filled in. I  only have access to the odoo GUI and developers view.
my model is called x_dagverslag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

- 1) Create new menu item name: "New sales order" in model sale.order
- 2) Set default view to formview
- 3) Look for the action number **action=885**
  in this example 885 3)
- 3) make link :

  ```
  <button name="885" type="action" class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-shopping-cart" string="New order" context="{'default_partner_id': x_customerid}"/>
  ```
- 4) Replace x_customerid with the name of your partner id field